# Check if web service is running

Tags: java, selenium, web-services, automation

How can I check if the server is working properly by sending a request to the web service every few minutes and getting back the response and notifying the concerned person?

Can this be achieved by using Java and Selenium?

Comment: If API is down it will not return you 200

Comment: You don't need selenium for this. In fact, this is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a daemon thread constantly hitting the service in fixed time interval and check on http response code(200 if service is UP). You can also send a mail through JAVA code itself provided you have SMTP server.